# Opening a workspace via vscode uri

Tags: visual-studio-code, redirect, hyperlink, uri, workspace

Does VS Code API natively support opening a workspace directly via URI
e.g. vscode://ssh-remote+mylinuxbox/home/user/project
where 'project' contains a .code-workspace file
or would I need to register a custom uri handler as mentioned here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.registerUriHandler

I've tried simply opening vscode uris hoping workspaces would open, but I'm not certain this behavior exists natively